# Minimongo errors when I try to update a document containing an array

Tags: mongodb, meteor, minimongo, angular-meteor

I'm having trouble updating an array that is contained in a document using angular-meteor.  Minimongo throws an error `documentMatches needs a document`.

The document that throws this error on update is shown below.  One thing it contains is an array of `_id`s.  This array contains the display order of some certain documents.  It looks like this:

```
{
  _id:"...",
  profileQuestions:{
    profileQuestionsOrder:["jqKMp7rzsZApauwYE","jakehILKehpkdhj"]
  }
}
```

I have attached this using `$scope.meteorObject` to a variable called `$scope.settings`. When I remove an item from this array and then save with `.save()`, I get the error.  The funny thing is, when I add an item to the array, and then save, there is no problem! I can also add other keys to the settings object with no issue.  It's just the array that causes problems.

I used chrome's debugger to see what was going on when the error was thrown, and  here is the code that throws the error:

```
  documentMatches: function (doc) {
    if (!doc || typeof doc !== "object") {
      throw Error("documentMatches needs a document");
    }
    return this._docMatcher(doc);
  },
```

What's crazy is that `doc` here is actually the first item in the profileQuestionsOrder array - it is simply a string containing a document id.  It seems like miniMongo is getting confused about this array.  I can put in any other property, and it has no error.  But when I remove an item from this array, it has problems.

By the way, when I do not save the object to the db, I can see that it was correctly altered, splicing one element out of the array.

Comment: where's the code where you try to update the doc?

Comment: In Angular-meteor, you just write $scope.settings.save(), and it's supposed to save it all.  I think there may be a bug in the $meteorObject code.  I changed to use a collection instead and it works.